# Hide a part of input as password

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<input type="text">` in which i consider the pattern A B C

Example value:

> Hello guys this is a sample

Hello is A

guys is B

this is a sample is C

I would like to transform C to be like if it was a type="password" only for C.
But I must use only one input.

So, after there are 2 spaces, next part become hidden.

Is it possible ?

I can use css/js.

Comment: not really and this would not be very secure...

Comment: you cannot do this on one input, you can probably do this on contenteditable div.

Comment: @DanielA.White this is not a password

Comment: This is possible... So u want 2first 2 words shown and rest of after these words need to be hide .. right?

Comment: @AtulRajput exact

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a code to do it. You need to list 'keydown' and 'keyup' events.

Maybe this example can be near that you want.
https://codesandbox.io/s/hide-part-input-q5yzd

In HTML

```
<body>
  <h1>Example</h1>

  <label>Type here the word</label><input id="input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; width: 300px" />
  <br />
  <label>Without transform</label>
  <input id="input2" type="text" disabled style="margin-left: 10px; width: 300px" />

  <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </p>
</body>
```

And in javascript:

```
import './styles.css';

let inputTextOriginal = [];
let inputTextModified = [];
let numSpaces = 0;

const node = document.getElementById('input');
console.log('node', node);

node.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  const keycode = event.keyCode;
  console.log('keycode', keycode);
  if (
    (keycode > 47 && keycode < 58) ||  // number keys
    keycode === 32 ||                  // spacebar 
    (keycode > 64 && keycode < 91) ||  // letter keys
    (keycode > 95 && keycode < 112)    // numpad keys
  ) {

    inputTextOriginal.push(event.key);

    if (numSpaces >= 2) {
      inputTextModified.push('*');
    } else {
      inputTextModified.push(event.key);
    }

    if (keycode === 32) {
      numSpaces++;
    }
  }

  if (keycode === 8) {
    inputTextModified.pop();
    let deleteKey = inputTextOriginal.pop();
    if (deleteKey === ' ') {
      numSpaces--;
    }
  }
});

node.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  node.value = inputTextModified.join('');
  document.getElementById('input2').value = inputTextOriginal.join('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done using a single input field. One input field can have one type. You can have a hacky solution where you can put two inputs wrapped inside a div. So that, it appears as one input only.

Hope this helps